# Java: Encrypting and Decrypting using DES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to create a simple encryption/decryption program, but i'm having problems when decrypting. The way the program works, I get string input from the user, then encrypt using DES, convert to Base64 and give the user the converted secret key. However, when I get the secret key from the user and I try to decrypt, I get either error:

java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: (null)

or

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

I don't know if the fault is at the time of encryption or if it's the decryption. Here's the respective snippets of code:

```
   import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
   public static boolean encrypt(byte[] text){

    Boolean yorn = false;
    try{
        myDesKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        //myDeskKey = myDesKey.toString();
        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

//I felt it would be better seeing the secret key as "woatDnBJLAg="  instead of  "com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@18765"

        if (myDesKey != null) {
           stringKey = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myDesKey.getEncoded());

            System.out.println("actual secret_key:" + myDesKey);

            byte[] encodedKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(stringKey);

            myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length,
                    "DES");
            System.out.println("after encode & decode secret_key:"
                    + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myDesKey.getEncoded()));
            }
        textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

    yorn = true;
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2,50);
    textArea.setText("Your encryption key is:  " +  stringKey + " . Ensure you store it in a safe place" );// + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(myDesKey.getEncoded()));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(textArea), "RESULT", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("There has been an error encrypting the file");
        yorn = false;
    }
        return yorn;
```

Decryption

```
  public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key,String key1)
  {
    String plainText = "";
    try{
        SecretKey myDesKey = key;
        if(key == null){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "We were unable to find your decryption key. Please enter your decryption key below: ");
        JTextArea textBox = new JTextArea(1,15);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(textBox),"Enter your decryption key ",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        //myDesKey = textBox.toSecretKey;
        }

    Cipher desCipher;
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
    byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    plainText = new String(textDecrypted);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, plainText, "DECRYPTED MESSAGE", 0);

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("There has been an error decrypting the file");
        System.out.println(e);
    }return plainText;
  }
}
```

I know that I'm probably getting the errors because i've combined so many jumbled bits of code from all over stack and I seem to have lost the plot, but any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: Vulnerability 1: you use DES - DES can no longer be considered as cryptographic cipher - it is too old and too weak. Vulnerability 2: you directly let the user enter a (base64 encoded) password. Use PBKDF2 and derive a key from the password.

Comment: Also note that is ASCII text is used as the key DES ignores the parity bit (generally) which is the LSB of the characters so that reduces the key space by another 8-bits.

Comment: For vulnerability 1, what would you consider to be a suitable alternative for DES that is not too difficult to implement? Secondly, how is the user entering their secret key seen as a vulnerability?And how do I use PBKDF2 to derive the password?

Comment: @SeyiOluwasanmi 1. Replace DES by AES. 2. DES is rather insecure because its key size is too small (56 bit). A user must enter a 8 byte key, but keys must consist of all kinds of bytes and not just printable characters. That is why users usually enter passwords, but passwords have low entropy and don't have a specific length which is necessary for block ciphers. That is why key derivation is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different ciphers. `Cipher.getInstance("DES")` is not fully specified, so it probably defaults to `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")` which is different from the CBC mode you're using during encryption.

Secondly, since you're using CBC mode, you need to manage the initialization vector (IV), but you don't do this at all. You can either provide the IV as a third parameter for `Cipher#init` or let it automatically be generated as you currently do, but then you have to send the IV (`desCipher.getIV()`) along with the ciphertext to the receiver. The IV doesn't have to be secret. A common way is to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

Lastly, the key you're using during decryption is not the same key that you've used during encryption, because you've re-encoded the key after encryption, but didn't decode it back.

Comment: If I use just the DES mode for encryption, would I still need to manage the IV?

Comment: DES is a block cipher and you're already using it for encryption. If you were to use ECB for encryption, then you don't need to manage the IV, but ECB is very insecure (see the [penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB)). I don't recommend it.

Comment: I think i'll use the DES mode until I get it working, because at my level it's more important to actually get it working rather than making sure it's secure. I'll work on making it more secure when I'm refining it in the future

Comment: could you please suggest the most efficient way of decoding the key? I'm using java 7 so I wasn't able to use the base 64 libraries and decoding is proving to be a real challenge

Comment: There are a lot of libraries for Base64 encoding. It you can't make it work, then you can do Hex encoding which is much shorter and available on this site. You just have to search for it.

Comment: @SeyiOluwasanmi Using AES in place of DES is no more difficult, just type "AES" instead of "DES" in the code. All the other issues presented applied equally to both. The only real difference is that AES is more secure.